# What is the closest equivalent to Melodyne in Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation

It's been over 15 years since the first versions of Melodyne were released. What Linux software equivalents exist? I need software that will enable me to move notes in audio such that they change in pitch and change their width to change their tempo.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFCjv4_jqAY&t=30s

Comment: Did you try run it with wine?

Comment: Should run with wine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cBIQQcN7Vo

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/celemony-melodyne/?platform=linux

Comment: Audacity? http://www.audacityteam.org/about/features/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ridgy said, it runs with [wine](https://www.winehq.org/). The standalone is working already, You can try to get a running version with [airwave](https://github.com/phantom-code/airwave) or another VST-Linux bridge in your DAW.

Update 12.05.2018: On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is airwave not working yet for me.
I'll reupdate this, if that changes. This post was originally created with an 16.04 or 17.10 install.

Comment: Well, damn, times changed. It works fine. Thanks!